# Jquery match for json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I'm trying to pull out data from my json using `match()` in my search function. Here's what I want to do using the string inputted in the textbox. It would then pull out data from my json array as long as there is a match. Here's what I have so far:

```
var data = [{
    "RM_Name": "Russ Martin",
    "Division": "East",
    "RM_Phone": "(603) 491-1259",
    "RC_Name": "Jacob Sucoff",
    "RC_Phone": "(800) 247-4154 x3403",
    "States_Covered": "MT,VT, NH, ME  (all firms)",
    "Latitude": 46.6797995,
    "Longitude": -110.044783,
    "Coordinates": "46.6797995,-110.044783"
}, {
    "RM_Name": "Carey Fortnam",
    "Division": "East",
    "RM_Phone": "(585)-259-7394",
    "RC_Name": "Matt Wrzesniewsky",
    "RC_Phone": "(800) 247-4154 x3088",
    "States_Covered": "NY- Upstate ex Rockland County (BD, FP)",
    "Latitude": 40.7056308,
    "Longitude": -73.9780035,
    "Coordinates": "40.7056308,-73.9780035"

}];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var rm_name = item.RM_Name,division = item.Division,rm_phone = item.RM_Phone,rc_name = item.RC_Name,rc_phone = item.RC_Phone,states = item.States_Covered;

    var dataset='<tr class="'+rm_name+' '+rc_name+'"><td>'+rm_name+'</td><td>'+division+'</td><td>'+rm_phone+'</td><td>'+rc_name+'</td><td>'+rc_phone+'</td><td>'+states+'</td></tr>';

    $('.rm-data').append(dataset);
});

$('#search').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {   
        search();
    }
}).on('change', function (e) {
    search();
});

function search() {
    var query = $('#search').val();

    // empty?
    if(query === "")
    {
        $('.rm-data tr').show();
        return;
    }

    $('.rm-data tr').hide();
    $('.error-msg').hide();

    if ($('.rm-data tr').hasClass(query)) {
        $('.rm-data tr:contains(' + query + ')').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $('.rm-data tr:contains(' + query + ')').slideDown().show();
        });
    }
    else {
        //JSON Match Finder
        $.getJSON(data, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var test= item.RM_Name+' '+item.RC_Name;
                var regex = new RegExp(query);
                var test2 = test.match(regex);
                   console.dir(test2);

            });
        });

        var error = '<div class="error-msg">Contact Not Found</div>';
        $('.rm-table-search').append(error);
        if ($('.error-msg').length == 0) {
            $('.rm-table').append(error);
        }
        else {
            $('.rm-table').append('');
        }
    }          
}
```

I am able to find matches using this code but I cannot pull the data out. Is there anyway I can do this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/HEdc2/39/) here.

Just sharing my output so far via console.log()

```
["Ru", index: 0, input: "Russ MartinJacob Sucoff", $family: function, $constructor: function, pop: function…]
 ab-rm.js:80
6
null ab-rm.js:80
["Ru", index: 18, input: "Kevin GangMichael Rus", $family: function, $constructor: function, pop: function…]
 ab-rm.js:80
12
null ab-rm.js:80
["Ru", index: 0, input: "Russ CorbyNatasha Fomenko", $family: function, $constructor: function, pop: function…]
 ab-rm.js:80
8
null ab-rm.js:80
["Ru", index: 6, input: "Laura RupsisKenny Meyer", $family: function, $constructor: function, pop: function…]
```

Comment: Are these actual phone numbers and names of real people? If they are, you probably want to obfuscate them in some way.

Comment: @ajm nope just sample data thanks for the concern

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is remove the `$.getJSON(data, function (data) { });` that surrounds your `$.each()` as that is trying to do an ajax call but all your sending it is a block of JSON instead of a url. Threw together this fiddle and removed the getJSON and seems to work if you search for 'Russ': http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/hzCQ9/
Let me know if I've missed something

Comment: @andyface: same result also what I want to know is how do i pull it out to display in my html

Comment: @a_miguel6687 ahh, sorry, didn't read the last line. Think I understand what you're after now.

Comment: @a_miguel6687 Ok, forgive me if I still haven't quite got this, but if you add `console.log(data[i]);` after your `console.dir()` call, does that display the information you're after?

Comment: @andyface i tried console.log(test2.input) and this yields the first result which I don't understand since I got like 4 results because im in the each loop. can I specify which index to get only?

Comment: `i` should be the index of the current item in the each loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52042/discussion-between-a-miguel6687-and-andyface)

Comment: @a_miguel6687 give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/HEdc2/42/

Comment: @balexandre this is pretty close to what I want to do, However how do I show results that yield true only?

Comment: to much work there! you need to create a div and show it, needs to be cross browser as well... that is why I have given you what **typeahead** that you could reuse. You can't expect that we would do all your work, we simply point you in the right direction.

Comment: @balexandre yeah thanks for that the hints were really helpful :)

Comment: @balexandre followup question how can I apply your code if I combine RM_Name and RC_Name to form a new array?

Comment: @a_miguel6687 in the code with typeahead that I gave you from your other question, just add to the array what you want, that is in the `.each()` loop.

Comment: @balexandre thanks! please see fiddle for the output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out based on balexandre's idea:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var rm_name = item.RM_Name,
        division = item.Division,
        rm_phone = item.RM_Phone,
        rc_name = item.RC_Name,
        rc_phone = item.RC_Phone,
        states = item.States_Covered;

    var dataset = '<tr class="' + rm_name + ' ' + rc_name + '"><td>' + rm_name + '</td><td>' + division + '</td><td>' + rm_phone + '</td><td>' + rc_name + '</td><td>' + rc_phone + '</td><td>' + states + '</td></tr>';

    $('.rm-data').append(dataset);
});

function search() {
    var query = $('#search').val();

    $('.rm-data tr').hide();
    $('.error-msg').hide();

    if ($('.rm-data tr').hasClass(query)) {
        $('.rm-data tr:contains(' + query + ')').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $('.rm-data tr:contains(' + query + ')').slideDown().show();
        });
    } else {
            var combined_array = [];
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                combined_array.push(item.RM_Name);
                combined_array.push(item.RC_Name);

            });
            $.each(combined_array, function (i, item) {
                var contents = item;
                var array_check = item.indexOf(query) >= 0;
                var matches = '<a href="#" class="search-match ' + array_check + '">'+contents+'</a>';

                $('#search-helper-container').append(matches);
                $('.false').remove();
                $('#search-helper-container').css('display', 'block');

            });


        var error = '<div class="error-msg">Contact Not Found</div>';
        $('.rm-table-search').append(error);
        if ($('.error-msg').length == 0) {
            $('.rm-table').append(error);
        } else {
            $('.rm-table').append('');
        }

    }


}

$('#search-button').on('click', function () {
    search();

});

$('#search').on('focus', function () {
    $('#search').val('');
    $('.true').remove();
    $('#search-helper-container').css('display', 'none');
});

$('#search-helper-container').on('click', 'a.search-match', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputVal = $(this).text();
    $('#search').val(inputVal);
});
```

And a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/HEdc2/61/) here.